# Execute Ajax queries one after one with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to execute ajax post requests one after one and stop only when the result is something like "done". But I can't figure out why it is not looping...I get a json answer but I can't do anything with success response.
My code so far:

```
var index = 0;
function crawler(textarea) {
        index   = 0;
        if(url != ''){
            if(/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(url)){
                execute_queue(index);
            }
        }
    };

function execute_queue(index)
    {    
        url     = strip_tags($('#input-website').val().trim());
        folders = strip_tags($('#excluded-folders').val().trim());
        $.ajax( {    
            url: 'xxx',
            cache:  false,
            type : 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: {url:url, folders:folders, current:index},
            success: function(response)
            {
                index++;          
                execute_queue(index);
            }

        });
};
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please remove `async: false`. It's really bad practice. Any errors in the console?

Comment: have you checked what "response" returns?

Comment: Make an array of requests, make a function to do the AJAX request and when result is returned, run the next array item request, do this until you get what you want.

Comment: @Ann-SophieAngermüller I get a json response but I can't do an alert() or something with it...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No any error in the console

Comment: @ÉmilieRobert use  console.log(response); to check in your browser console what the response exactly is.

Comment: @Ann-SophieAngermüller Can't do anything with response, that's the thing, can't alert() it or log it in console but I see the json response in firebug console.

Comment: well this indicates that your ajax does not return a successfull. have you checked the php script for failures?

Comment: for async this might be useful https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ to give a try

Comment: code seems all right , you must check your response and add your condition to terminate the looping if it start

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the request failed, this is straight from the JQuery manaual:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

More info [found here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), success will not be called if the URL responds with an error.

**UPDATE:**
I think your code should look something like this:

```
var index = 0;
function crawler(textarea) {
        index   = 0;
        if(url != ''){
            if(/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(url)){
                execute_queue(index);
            }
        }
    };

function execute_queue(index)
    {    
        url     = strip_tags($('#input-website').val().trim());
        folders = strip_tags($('#excluded-folders').val().trim());
        $.ajax( {    
            url: 'xxx',
            cache:  false,
            type : 'POST',
            data: {url:url, folders:folders, current:index},
            success: function(response)
            {
                index++;          
                execute_queue(index);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: I get a json response, that's the thing. Added your answer and it alerts "error" and "complete"...